# jQuery Mobile Web App - clicking link to another page - page flashes content then blanks

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

This is an issue I ran into before and I am still unsure as to why it happens.

The page in question is - http://nexrem.com/dragontimer/testdir/mobile/index.html

When you hit the Select server button, the page flashes the content that should be there, then its blank! One way I know this can be fixed is by adding `data-ajax="false"` to the link; however if I do that, then I run into another problem: on iPhone if I add the page to my home screen and then run it - click the 'Select Server' - opens up a browser instead of staying within the web app.

My goal is for users to be able to add the page to their home screen, with no url bar and just run all pages from within. It seems that having `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />` and the `data-ajax="false"` together isn't working out.

So basically 2 things:

- How can I fix the screen flashing and displaying blank (unless refreshed)
- or how can I have the web app with no toolbar and not open the browser every time user clicks buttons?

Thank You

**Edit:** Here is the code for index.html and servers.html

index.html - http://pastebin.com/Qh5s7QRp

servers.html - http://pastebin.com/Exv2MJrS

Comment: Hi! Could you post your code ?

Comment: @Littm -Edited post with the links to source code. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

In your file `index.html`, include `rel="external"` instead of `data-ajax="false"` inside the definition of your link `Select server`.

So, you should have this instead:

```
<a href="servers.html" data-role="button" data-theme="c" rel="external">Select server</a>
```

You may also need to replace every `data-ajax="false"`, that you included in the `<a>` links of both your HTML files `index.html` and `servers.html`, with `rel="external"`.

---

Check the online doc for more information about `rel="external"` at http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-links.html :

> Links that point to other domains or that have **rel="external"**,
>   **data-ajax="false"** or target attributes will not be loaded with Ajax.
>   Instead, these links will cause a full page refresh with no animated
>   transition. Both attributes (**rel="external"** and **data-ajax="false"**)
>   have the same effect, but a different semantic meaning: **rel="external"**
>   should be used when linking to another site or domain, while
>   **data-ajax="false"** is useful for simply opting a page within your
>   domain from being loaded via Ajax. Because of security restrictions,
>   the framework always opts links to external domains out of the Ajax
>   behavior.

Hope this helps.